# unknown syntax error in python (I really can't find out where is my error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

This is my code:

```
import math

k = int(input("Give the term number: "))
result = 0

for x in range(k):
    result += 2*pow(-1,k)*pow(3,(0.5-k))/(2k+1)

print ("After ", k, "terms, ", "the appoximation is ", result)
```

The syntax error is showing up on line 7, which is the result after the for loop.
I know this kind of errors usually is missing parenthesis or etc. But I really don't know where my error is.

Comment: ignore the missing space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error in following line

```
result += 2*pow(-1,k)*pow(3,(0.5-k))/`(2k+1)`
```

2k+1 should be 2*k

Comment: OMG, I knew it should be this kind of stupid error, ty so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
k = int(input("Give the term number: "))
result = 0

for x in range(k):
    result += 2*pow(-1,k)*pow(3,(0.5-k))/((2*k)+1)
print ("After ", k, "terms, ", "the appoximation is ", result)
```

Comment: (2*K) instead of 2k

Comment: add your comment to your answer